# Events are not visible on wso2 esb 5.0.0 analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-esb

I am trying to configure `wso2 esb5.0.0` with `esb analytics`. I used default configs as given in the wso2 documentation. `ESB` is running on `9443` and esb analytics is running on `9444`. I am invoking my `test` proxy but there is not entry in `analytics` dashboard. Below are the `configs` and `proxy`.

Synapse.properties

```
# Configuration to enable mediation flow analytics

mediation.flow.statistics.enable=true

mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.payloads=true

mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.properties=true

mediation.flow.statistics.event.consume.interval=1000

mediation.flow.statistics.event.clean.interval=15000



# Configuration to enable statistics globally irrespective of the individual artifact level setting

mediation.flow.statistics.collect.all=true
```

Proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="test"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator="*****"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <respond/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Can anyone help what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You configured publishing analytics correctly and didn't miss anything. As analytics server retrieving data, you may have to wait around few minutes while publishing data.

And you can verify whether your events are publishing to analytics node via Data explorer in management console.

You have to navigate to management console (https://localhost:9444/carbon) and then to data explorer (Home  > Manage > Interactive Analytics > Data Explorer). And check for table values.

[image: Data Explorer]

Tested sample scenario as you indicated in the question and it works properly.